# Where does `haskell-mode` look for libraries? (`stack`, GHC for OSX)

Tags: macos, haskell, emacs, haskell-stack

I'm using Emacs 24.5 and the latest GHC for OSX (let's call it GFO),

```
$ which stack
/Applications/ghc-7.10.3.app/Contents/bin/stack

$ which ghc
/Applications/ghc-7.10.3.app/Contents/bin/ghc
```

When compiling (`C-c C-l`) a module which requires libraries that are not in the GFO distribution, e.g. `vector`, `transformers`, I obviously get a series of `Could not find module ..`.

Now, I know that these packages are available in the system (in `~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.3/`), because another project compiled them (via `stack build`).

### QUESTION

Where do I change the behaviour of `haskell-mode` when loading a module? Otherwise, what's the exact command that is issued with `C-c C-l`, and how do I make it aware of the additional context introduced by `stack`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you have ` '(haskell-process-type (quote auto))` it should pick stack for yo

Comment: @Carsten , it's already set to `'auto`, but this does not apply here. The module I need to load does not have a `stack.yaml` associated (it does not need to belong to a project). I'm only trying to load libraries that were compiled via stack for a separate, self-standing project. Or am I simply asking for something impossible because `stack` was not meant for this?

Comment: IMO it works when you put a cabal somewhere nearby - aside from this you could call `stack exec -- emacs`